# How do I factory reset an OBD2 ELM327 device (not reset ECU)?

Tags: obd, elm-327

it no longer puts out wifi  thank you

tried turnning it off for a day, it has no reset button on the unit or PCB

here is more information: Here is more information  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/245951/wi-fi-station-wont-connect-to-ap-wpa2-psk

Comment: Check the instructions.

Comment: most likely you will have to remove the device from your pc/phone and set it up again.you wil have to give a lot more information in your question to get a detailed answer.

Comment: Here is more information  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/245951/wi-fi-station-wont-connect-to-ap-wpa2-psk

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard procedure as all vendors are using custom hardware (although many are based on the ancient ELM327 "reference" design). If a power-cycle doesnot help, it's most likely broken or (depending on its capabilities) misconfigured in a state that prevents the WiFi to come up.

Check with the vendor whether it has a hidden reset button or something along those lines.